# Iterate through a JSON list with JS function

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to append some JSON results, I'm working with a list (array?) and there's multiple elements, I know I can add some styling directly in the JS code but I'm more comfortable with this method. How can I iterate through elements and implement in some divs, then create similar divs with the next elements.

The only way to achieve that goal afaik is like this:

```
$("#article").append(data[i].datetime + data[i].headline + "<br />" + "<hr />"       + data[i].summary);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Project JS 02</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div class="container container-table">
<div class="row vertical-center-row">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%" class="search" id="getnews">Get News!</button>
  <h1 id="headline"></h1><br>
  <h3 id="datetime"></h3><br>
  <div id="summary"></div><br>
  <h6 id="source"></h6><br>

  </div>

</div>
</div>


  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
document.getElementById("getnews").addEventListener("click", function () {

 var newsurl = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/news"

 $.getJSON(newsurl, function (data) {

  for (i in data)
  {
    $("#headline").append(data[i].headline);
    $("#datetime").append(data[i].datetime);
    $("#summary").append(data[i].summary);
    $("#source").append(data[i].source);

  }

})

})

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not totally sure what the question asks.. What you are doing seems okay. Probably you are looking to ease your task of rendering your api response. The keywords to search online are `frontend js html templating engine`. there is handlebars.js that is popular among other.

Comment: @Vasif No my question is how to render those articles correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating the elements (with jQuery) as needed, and appending them to a container:

```js
$("#getnews").on("click", function () {
    var newsurl = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/news"
    $('#data').text("...loading...");
    $.getJSON(newsurl, function (data) {
        $('#data').html("");
        data.forEach(function (article) {
            $('#data').append(
                $('<h1>').text(article.headline),
                $('<h3>').text(article.datetime),
                $('<div>').text(article.summary),
                $('<h6>').text(article.source)
            );
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary search" 
        style="width: 100%" id="getnews">Get News!</button>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First: remove the ids. If you want to create similar containers, the ids will be there multiple times, that won't work.

Second: Take the div with `$('.row.vertical-center-row')` and clone it.

Third: set the values at the cloned HTMLNode und append it to `$('.container.container-table')`

Something like that (*untested*):

```
<div class="container container-table">
  <div class="row vertical-center-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%" class="search" class="getnews">Get News!</button>
      <h1 class="headline"></h1><br>
      <h3 class="datetime"></h3><br>
      <div class="summary"></div><br>
      <h6 class="source"></h6><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("getnews").forEach((el)=>el.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var newsurl = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/news"
  $.getJSON(newsurl, function (data) {
    var $elClone = $('.row.vertical-center-row').clone(true).appendTo($('.container.container-table'));
    for (i in data) {
      $(".headline", $elClone).append(data[i].headline);
      $(".datetime", $elClone).append(data[i].datetime);
      $(".summary", $elClone).append(data[i].summary);
      $(".source", $elClone).append(data[i].source);
    }
  })
}));
</script>
```